# wxPython Navigation Panel (like Finder (Mac OS X), Nautilus (Ubuntu), Explorer (Windows 7))

Tags: python, navigation, wxpython

My question is simple how to get make a navigation panel that is similar to 
Finder (Mac OS X)

[image: Finder]

Explorer (Windows 7)
[image: Windows Explorer]

Nautilus (Ubuntu)

[image: Nautilus]

As for using a wx.TreeCtrl that does not work....

Example

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/500311/

As you can see the first problem is that there is a huge pink strip that is on the left and you can't remove it, second only on root or else you have to put more of a buffer for the hidden buffer, second kludgy, third not really what either of the three example looks like at all.

So how can I get a navigation panel similar to the examples above (well except for the tree ctrl example :p)

==== UPDATE =====

On Windows (Windows 7 at least) there is no problem of the left side having a white column

Might be that on Linux and MacOS X the tree ctrl widget is generically drawn... if some one could run the example above on MacOS X and see if there is a pink column (pink because the example sets that to the background color) to the left of the tree ctrl.

==== Update 2 =====
iTunes as an example
[image: Navigation Bar Example]

There seems to be a little misunderstanding with the question it isn't a file manager folder view I am looking for but the navigation panel side I am.

For example iTunes also has this but isn't a file manager what they all have is on the left side there are a bunch of click able "tabs" that are used to navigate (for example in iTunes there is music, movies, tv shows, audiobooks, apps all under library)

Also the problem is that a tree ctrl DOESN'T work on Linux (see image below)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Treebook](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Treebook).

**update:**

Alternatively, try doing something with [wx.lib.agw.foldpanelbar](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.foldpanelbar-module.html). Check out it's demo in the demo suite, depending on what you actually need it may be enough. If not, you can always make your own from scratch.

Comment: the navigation part uses a tree ctrl so still has the same problems of the tree ctrl and left side empty pixels

Comment: No real answer but yours did give me some ideas sadly none of them answer the question oh well...

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for browsing directory structure:

```
import os
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.dir = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self.panel, size=(200, -1), style=wx.DIRCTRL_DIR_ONLY)
        self.files = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.LC_LIST)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.dir, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.files, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)  
        self.Show()

        self.dir.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelect)


    def OnSelect(self, e):
        self.files.ClearAll()
        list = os.listdir(self.dir.GetPath())
        for a in reversed(list):
            self.files.InsertStringItem(0, a)


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None, size=(600, 400))
app.MainLoop()
```

Some helpful examples are here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#File_Hunter
- http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/08/31/file-list-with-icons-on-wxpython-windows

If you just would like similar widget, have a look at [`wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl-module.html). It may not be exactly 100% what you want, but there is a source of this widget in wxpython, so you can modify it to match your needs.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl as CT

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.dir = CT.CustomTreeCtrl(self.panel, size=(100, -1), 
                                     style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER,
                                     agwStyle=CT.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT | CT.TR_HIDE_ROOT | CT.TR_NO_LINES | CT.TR_ROW_LINES)           

        root = self.dir.AddRoot("The Root Item")
        child = self.dir.AppendItem(root, "Test")
        child = self.dir.AppendItem(child, "Test 2")
        child = self.dir.AppendItem(child, "Test 3")
        child = self.dir.AppendItem(root, "Test 4")

        self.dir.ExpandAll()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.dir, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)  
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None, size=(200, 300))
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the HyperTreeList control with the TR_TWIST_BUTTON style applied? That would make it look more like the Apple finder. It's also pure python and easier to hack yourself than the normal TreeCtrl. If you need the Windows Explorer look, you might want to look at the ListCtrl, ObjectListView or the UltimateListCtrl. There are demos for all of these in the wxPython demo (except for ObjectListView since it's not included with wxPython).